# Having problems with recursive array objects (stdClass Object)

Tags: php

I'm hoping someone can help me with my syntax.  I think that's the issue.  I'm trying to have the loop go through display the chosen object, but it's not working.  Here is my code.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result_count] => 2
    [total_count] => 2
    [next_offset] => 2
    [entry_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => da2b0ab5-873b-d9a8-0fcd-5180871e57eb
                [module_name] => Project
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [description] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => description
                                [value] => soccer is fun!!!
                            )

                        [priority] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => priority
                                [value] => Primary
                            )

                        [total_years_played_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => total_years_played_c
                                [value] => 5
                            )

                        [sport_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => sport_c
                                [value] => Soccer
                            )

                        [high_school_exp_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => high_school_exp_c
                                [value] => 2
                            )

                        [varsity_exp_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => varsity_exp_c
                                [value] => default
                            )

                        [hand_right_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => hand_right_c
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                        [hand_left_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => hand_left_c
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                        [foot_right_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => foot_right_c
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                        [foot_left_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => foot_left_c
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                        [specialskills_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => specialskills_c
                                [value] => 
                            )

                        [varsity_starter_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => varsity_starter_c
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2e805552-c887-2b2e-a9e5-518087f3f87a
                [module_name] => Project
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [description] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => description
                                [value] => I bleed for hockey... I will teach your kid to put them on the boards and take no prisoners!
                            )

                        [priority] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => priority
                                [value] => Secondary
                            )

                        [total_years_played_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => total_years_played_c
                                [value] => 7
                            )

                        [sport_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => sport_c
                                [value] => Hockey
                            )

                        [high_school_exp_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => high_school_exp_c
                                [value] => 3
                            )

                        [varsity_exp_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => varsity_exp_c
                                [value] => 2
                            )

                        [hand_right_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => hand_right_c
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                        [hand_left_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => hand_left_c
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                        [foot_right_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => foot_right_c
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                        [foot_left_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => foot_left_c
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                        [specialskills_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => specialskills_c
                                [value] => 
                            )

                        [varsity_starter_c] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => varsity_starter_c
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[relationship_list] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Here is the PHP that I am using.  For now, I'm just wanting to echo the name of sport_c (one should be Hockey, the other should be Soccer)

```
<?

foreach($response->entry_list as $sports) {
if(!empty($sports->name_value_list->sport_c)) {
   $sport_list = $sports->name_value_list->sport_c;
   $sport_name = $sport_list->value;
}
}

echo $sport_name;

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Does it not do anything? Something, but not what you expect? Are there error messages?

Comment: It's not echoing the two sport names (with the echo $sport_name; )

Comment: The use of 'short open tags' is discouraged, as they might be disabled on other servers.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `echo` statement within the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($response->entry_list as $sports) {
    if(!empty($sports->name_value_list->sport_c)) {
        $sport_list = $sports->name_value_list->sport_c;
        $sport_name = $sport_list->value;
    }
    echo $sport_name;
}
```

Comment: @lobstahcrushah: Is there more code in your files? Are you sure `$response` is the exact same object as displayed above? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I'm getting this error.  I think you are on to something Marcel.     Notice: Undefined variable: response

Comment: @lobstahcrushah: So `$response` is *not* the same as the object. Where should `$response` be defined?

Comment: I'm in nested object iteraton hell... looks like I need to read more... ;)  I'm just wanting to be able to display the 2 sports later in the page (using an echo statement), by calling up the appropriate variable...

Comment: @lobstahcrushah: Yes, but if `$response` is not defined, you won't get the two sports out of it. So, where does your object come from? If you execute only the piece of code you provided, there is indeed no `$response`. Where should it be defined? And how did you get the object you showed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29249/discussion-between-lobstahcrushah-and-marcel-korpel)